# Ошибка phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, linux, phpmyadmin

Создаю таблицу, вроде все норм, но  если выйти из таблицы и зайти обратно то возникают ошибки:

```
Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613
[![count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace][1]][1]

./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2079: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'test_db',
string 'f',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `f`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'test_db',
string 'f',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `f`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

Еще есть [скрин](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhRiB.png).

Comment: Видимо поставили php 7.2, в котором стало появляться это предупреждение, когда вызывается count(null) или count(false). Можете попробовать отключить warning'и в php.ini

Comment: @DmitryKozlov а как это сделать? А ничего если php совсем не установлен? У меня только mssql-server и phpmyadmin

Comment: https://www.komtet.ru/lib/plangs/php/otklyuchenie-pokaza-notice-i-warning-v-logah

Comment: @DmitryKozlov А это вообще норма, что ошибок  так много?

Comment: Это не ошибка, это предупреждение. Появилось с php 7.2. Это довольно новая версия. Откатитесь на предыдущую 7.1

Comment: строка 613 решение есть в англ ветке

Comment: В какой ветке? Можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 2):

Открываем на изменение библиотеку:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
```

Далее находим (Ctrl+W) => строку:

```
(count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

и меняем ее на:

```
((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
```

Сохраняем изменения Ctrl+O и закрываем Ctrl+x
Радуемся)) 
Также чтобы убрать ошибку импорта/экспорта которая возникает в php7.2:
Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551
изменяем плагин plugin_interface.lib.php

```
sudo nano /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php
```

Находим Ctrl+w следующий код:
    if (! is_null($options) && count($options) > 0) {
или

```
if ($options != null && count($options) > 0)
```

и меняем на следующее:

```
if (! is_null($options) && count((array)$options) > 0) {
```

Сохраняемся и радуемся))

Comment: В первом варианте исправления есть другая ошибка. Там на следующей строчке нужно будет одну скобку удалить :)